# Argument 2 passed to Google_Service_Gmail_UsersMessages_Resource::send() must be an instance of Google_Service_Gmail_Message, string given

Tags: php, laravel, gmail-api

I'm working on **Gmail API** with **Laravel**.

I'm getting the error:

> Argument 2 passed to
>   Google_Service_Gmail_UsersMessages_Resource::send() must be an
>   instance of Google_Service_Gmail_Message, string given

Here what is instance of `Google_Service_Gmail_Message`?. I'm giving `string` and what should i give?

my code is

```
public function sendMessage($message) {
try {
$client = $this->getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$userId = 'me';
$message = "test";
$message = $service->users_messages->send($userId, $message);
print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . ' sent.';
return $message;
} catch (Exception $e) {
 print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

the `send` method with two argument is at `line 7`

Comment: The method `send()`, member of the `Google_Service_Gmail_UsersMessages_Resource` class, expects two parameters (or arguments) when called, being one of them (the second) an instance of the `Google_Service_Gmail_Message` class. Instead of it, you're passing a string. This is the most I can say by only reading your error message. If you need more help, you'll need to share your code that generates this issue.

Comment: @Alan Machado, the code i'm dealing with

Comment: There you go, right here: `$message = $service->users_messages->send($userId, $message);`, the var message is a string containing "test", when it should be an instance of `Google_Service_Gmail_Message`. You have to read the API documentation to see how you create a new message to send (starting with `$message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//prepare the mail with PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->Encoding = "base64";

//supply with your header info, body etc...
$mail->Subject = "You've got mail!";
...

//create the MIME Message
$mail->preSend();
$mime = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
$mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($mime), '+/', '-_'), '=');

//create the Gmail Message

> $message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();

$message->setRaw($mime);
$message = $service->users_messages->send('me',$message);

Comment: i used to create mime message manually, but looks like your answer will help me to update my application so mime message will be created efficiently. Cheers!